# The property editor with alias imulus archetype does not exist on umbraco cloud

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-cloud

Getting this error on Umbraco cloud for imulus archetype despite it being existent in project:

Message:
No property editor found, converting to a Label

Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: The property editor with alias Imulus.Archetype does not exist

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Archetype binary (the `.dll` in the bin folder of your site) has not been pushed to your Cloud repository. Could you verify that it is actually added to your git repository?

Comment: Yes it was missing but it is still displaying the same error

Comment: If you go to Data Types in your Cloud site, click to create a new one - do you have Archetype as an option? (that would indicate that it has actually loaded the .dll correctly).

Comment: Thanks for the help,No that's not available in live site backoffice, but dll seems to be present on the live site otherwise